# What is the best way to keep authentication state

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie in Android and Firebase. I develop a classroom application that has 2 side, which are teacher and student, and store data on the Firebase. I want to set alarms on student side to alert their class time.

I have an `AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` class to notify student, and call it on `MainActivity` class.

I stored boolean `isStudent` and `isLecturer` on the `Application` class, also has getter and setter method. When which one is login, set that one is true. But the problem is it true just one time when login, then it all false. So, I want to know that how to keep the login state to tell the application that "this is student" or "this is teacher".

P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You could store `isLecturer` and `isStudent` in shared preferences: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to use  persistence storage. You can use database or shared preference. On login set the property for student or lecturer as true or false (or you can store 0 OR 1) and store that in storage (like shared preference) and then once you kill your app and on re launch your app get that property from storage and base upon that take your actions. If you have any splash screen you can test the same thing and navigate accordingly. For shared preference guide you may refer below link

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this , first initialize boolean isStudent = false and isLecture = false 
 when user sign in  check whether your user is student or lecture . based on that condition ..

```
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
       if(user!=null) 
       { 
          // check user is student or Lecture
        if(user == student){   
           // change status of boolean to true
            boolean isStudent= true 
          //save SP_isStudent = true in sharedprefenence
         // get status of boolean form sharedPreference
          if(SP_isStudent == true){  
            // do your task.
           } else{
          // show toast " user is not currently signin"
          }
        }

   else{
       boolean isLecture = true
     //save SP_isLecture = true in sharedprefenence ,
     // get status of isLecture from shared preference
      if(SP_isLecture == true{
       // do your task.
         }else{
      //show toast " user is not currently signin" 
      } 
     }
   }
  }
 };
```

then in

```
    onResume () {
     // check status of boolean for isStudent and isLecture 
    //and do your task accordingly

 }
In onDestroy(){
// change boolean to false
}
```